# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'

Tags: angular

I have two projects - one on angular 5 - which all works, and angular 6..

My code:

```
public keyUp = new Subject<string>();
const observable = this.keyUp
      .map(value => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
      .flatMap((search) => {
        return Observable.of(search).delay(300);
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.filter = data;
      });
```

And errors:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>',
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'Observable'
```

My imports:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

I tried various imports, but the result was the same..

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: What's the version of Rxjs?

Comment: didnt help. rxjs 6.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not working in Angular 6, it's safe to assume that the version of Rxjs you're using is 5.5 or later.

The following syntax should be applicable in that case:

```
import { map, flatMap, delay, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

...

public keyUp = new Subject < string > ();
const observable = this.keyUp
  .pipe(
     map(value => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value),
     debounceTime(500),
     distinctUntilChanged(),
     flatMap((search) => {
       return of(search).pipe(delay(300));
     })
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.filter = data;
  });
```

Comment: "of" still the same. This.filter = data gives error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'. And how can I add .debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged() to map?

Comment: @user3577896, Sorry about that. Didn't notice them. Please try the updated solution. It should work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. One more thing, what about? How can I add this to map? .debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged()?

Comment: @user3577896, updated the answer to cater to those as well. All these are basically `pipe`able operators and can be added to the pipe separated by a comma(`,`). You can read and learn more about them on [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks